# How to add new customer in magento 2 admin

Tags: magento2, database

I'm trying to add a new customer in magento admin, after creating the credentials I can't seem to log in as per there is no password field upon creating.

Can anybody tell me how to add a new customer in magento 2 either via mysql or in magento admin.

Thanks

Comment: What's the issue in creating customer from admin?

Comment: for creating the password you can simply use the forgot password option at the front-end & get the new password generation link to your email & generate the password from there!

Answer (score 1):

you can do it from mysql and as well as custom script .

1. Mysql Way (magento 2)

open your database and go to table `customer_entity` the password is stored in column `password_hash`
[image]

here you need to enter the query like

```
UPDATE `customer_entity`SET `password_hash` = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxxadmin@123', 256), ':xxxxxxxx:1') WHERE `entity_id` = 810
```

here admin@123 is the password that we assigned and 810 is the customer id (named as entity_id under customer entity), please change it according to your requirement . also dont remove xxxxx , it is needed

let me know if it works for you , we can also change it via custom script , let me know if you need it .

Answer (score 0):

In latest M2 you cant add any kind of PW for customer, to do so for testing you have to create customer from admin and to change its PW run the following query in mysql:

```
UPDATE `customer_entity`
SET `password_hash` = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxxpassword', 256), ':xxxxxxxx:1')
WHERE `entity_id` = 145;
```

Let me know if you still have any issue ? 145 is customer id in my case and after xxxxxxxx 'password' will be your new password